# Visual Studio 2012: Creating project from existing source code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, driver, wdm

I want to create WDM kernel driver project (for x64 and win32 config).

I created one from VS File->New->Project from existing source code. For Project type there 4 options: Windows Application Project, Console, DLL, Static (LIB) project, and no other. So I create Lib and changed config (e.g. Platform Toolset:WindowsKernelModeDriver8.0, Type of driver: WDM etc) But its still showing Config for debug as Release/Debug and Win32.

When I try to create new x64, I had to copy from Win32. (PS: I have x64 and Win7/8 release/debug etc in other project). And later while trying to call StartService with driver - its failling with error #127. <- On Win 7 64 bit m/c.

But same thing if I compile with Debug/Win32 bit option and install with StartService on 32 m/c, it works just fine. Can anyone help me with this?

Why I created with existing code?: Because we have directory structure and that I have to maintain that.

Comment: What is this source code you're using? Is it a source for a valid WDK driver that you want to port into VS2012? If so, this can and should be done via `File->Open->Convert Sources/Dirs`. If it's just a code that you have, I'm not sure if _Creating project from existing source code_ is applicable for drivers. You better ask in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/threads

Comment: Thanks @icepack, I solved that, with existing option only, but don't know why config was behaving stupid. It should just give all normal option that what I believe. But never mind, my code worked on everything so! :)